# drawable-540x960 directory name invalid

Tags: android, directory, screen

In my application i have to support 540x960 screens.
I have created a directory named: `drawable-540x960` for containing all graphics items for this screen.
But i get this error: `invalid resource directory name  drawable-540x960`
What is going wrong with this name?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are giving wrong directory name for your screen .you can refer this from developer site go here https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

in that site See Table No :2 for qualifers for screen size

also one line you can find in that is :

```
If the available height is a concern for you, then you can do the same using the h<N>dp qualifier. Or, even combine the w<N>dp and h<N>dp qualifiers if you need to be really specific.
```

For Specify use of Screen Size 540x960  ,you need to add layout like below and it is valid way to define width and height used for that xml layout.

```
res/layout-w540dp-h960dp/any layout which you need put in side this folder
```

Comment: renaming layout like this gives an error( Resource not found )

Answer (score 8):

Well actually the answer is quite simple:

```
drawable-hdpi-960x540
```

1) You have to specify the density 
2) You have to name the height first

Comment: Thanks! used this to target Telstra TouchSmart 'drawable-mdpi-320x240'.

Comment: @ HArpreet @JonWarnerNet  :: for layout 540x960 which formate you use for layout folder , i mean to say how to declare drawable folder name and layout folder name for 540x960 resolution device?

Answer (score 3):

I have tried with different emulators...Finally i succeeded.Height should be first value.

```
    res/layout-long-port-hdpi-500x300/layout.xml  (For testing i created this emulator)
    res/layout-long-port-hdpi-960x540/layout.xml  (For Motorola Droid Razr, Motorola Droid Bionic, etc)
    res/layout-long-port-hdpi-800x480/layout.xml  (For Nexus)
```

Comment: :: i give drawable folder like just drawable-hdpi and i try with this your format for layout-long-port-hdpi-960x540 but in 540x960 device it gave me error like ResourceNotFound execption

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry to say but s.krueger's solution will not work if you have some other drawable like drawable-mdpi or drawablae-xhdpi or drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-hdpi. It won't take the drawable-hdpi-960x540.

You have to name the drawable as per your pixel density and the screen size. The calculation is here...

dpi = sqrt (540^2+960^2) / 4.3"(Device size) = ~256 dp = px / (dpi / 160) = 540 / (dpi / 160) = 330

The drawable will be named as drawable-sw330dp. I have tested this. And this works good. No problem with other drawables either. Layout Will be layout-sw330dp

Or you can try this by drawable-sw540p. I haven't tested it yet. But I guess it will work good. Layout Will be layout-sw540p

Comment: Awesome, drawable-sw330dp and layout-sw330dp worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Android didnt recognize drawable-540x960 because it is an invalid size qualifier

You might want to look at android's guideline on supporting different screens
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

Here are some examples valid identifiers

```
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```