# support 540x960 resolution in my android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen, android-screen-support

I want to support 540x960 screen resolution in my android application. 
How can I support this screen? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: -1 not really sure what your question is - you can't make layout work on this resolution, you need to know how to detect that specific resolution?

Comment: res/layout-w540dp-h960dp/any layout which you need put in side this folder

Comment: This is the solution that works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10931395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't develop to specific resolutions on Android. You write layouts which automatically scale to different sizes and aspect ratios. Make use of classes such as `RelativeLayout` to define how elements should be placed relative to each other, and allow them to adapt to the available space. You can also use Fragments to design for different orientations and physical sizes (e.g. tablet vs phone).

Take a look at this document:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

put inside AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>
```

Or take a look bellow links.

[Android Multiscreen Support in android : 540x960 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481073/android-multiscreen-support-in-android-540x960-issue)

OR

[How to support all the different resolutions of android products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403619/how-to-support-all-the-different-resolutions-of-android-products)

Answer (score 1):

res/layout-long-port-hdpi-960x540/layout.xml

height shold be come first